# Understanding the input data and arguments in node-soap

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-soap

I'm using the node-soap module, which lets you connect to web services using SOAP.
I've already tested the communication with the Soap-Server(Web Service) via SoapUI and it works great.

Currently i can display the input data for a method. In this example i want to find out the input data for the method Connection. I can identify it with this command: `client.describe().MachineWebService.MachineBinding.Connection`

My client code looks like this:

```
var soap = require('soap');
var url = './MachineWebService.wsdl';

 // var args ={name: 'value'}

 soap.createClient(url, function(err, client) {
 console.log(client.describe().MachineWebService.MachineBinding.Connection);
//client.Connection(args, function(err, result) {
//  console.log(result);

});
```

The result of my client code is:

```
{ input:
   { loginInformation:
       subElement {
         nsName: 'xsd:complexType',
         prefix: 'tns',
         name: 'complexType',
         children: [Object],
         xmlns: 'http://www.XXXX.com/web-service/1.0',
         valueKey: '$value',
         xmlKey: '$xml',
         ignoredNamespaces: [Object],
         '$name': 'LoginInformationType' } },
  output:
   { result:
       subElement {
         nsName: 'xsd:complexType',
         prefix: 'tns',
         name: 'complexType',
         children: [Object],
         xmlns: 'http://www.XXXX.com/web-service/1.0',
         valueKey: '$value',
         xmlKey: '$xml',
         ignoredNamespaces: [Object],
         '$name': 'LoginInformationResponseType' },
     errors:
       subElement {
         nsName: 'xsd:complexType',
         prefix: 'tns',
         name: 'complexType',
         children: [Object],
         xmlns: 'http://www.XXXX.com/web-service/1.0',
         valueKey: '$value',
         xmlKey: '$xml',
         ignoredNamespaces: [Object],
         '$name': 'ErrorResponseType' } } }
```

**Problem:**
Actually it is possible to identify the arguments easily with the help of the input data. But my input data looks very messy. I don't understand how to structure the arguments with the above input data. Any idea?